# SQL Insert statements on same line

Tags: php, sql

I am currently using PHP to build a learning platform and hoping to record the users response to questions asked - I have built the database and the questions over several php pages and using insert statements the response value is added to the database, however when the user moves to and answers the next question their answer is put on the next SQL line meaning large white space in the SQL database. Is there away to put the users response to each question on the same line or is this something I am just going to have to get used to and put up with?

My insert statements look like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO pro_NoMusic (question8a, question8b, question8c, question8d, question8e) 
      VALUES ('$_POST[question8a]','$_POST[question8b]','$_POST[question8c]','$_POST‌​[question8d]','$_POST[question8e]')";
```

My table has a column for each question:

```
question1a, question2Aa, question2Ab, question2Ac, question2Ad, question2Ae,
question2Ba, question2Bb, question2Bc, question2Bd, question2Be,
question2Ca, question2Cb, question2Cc, question2Cd, question2Ce,
question2Da, question2Db, question2Dc, question2Dd, question2De,
question3a,question3b, question3c, question3d, question3e, question4,
question5a, question5b, question5c, question5d, question5e, question6,
question7, question8a, question8b, question8c, question8d, question8e
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show your table definition and some bits of php code? It will make it easier for us to help you. You can edit the text of your question to do that.

Comment: Can you share your table structure to better understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you record which of your users is answering these questions?  Most designers would include some sort of `user_id` column in a table like this.

Pro tip: normalize this data. Many designers would use a table like this for such answers.

```
user_id      int(11)  
question     varchar(10)   values like '1a', '2Aa', '8d', etc.
answer       varchar(255)
ts           datetime
```

The primary key here might be a compound key of (user_id, question).  This table will contain one row per answer to any question, rather than a whole mess of columns with answers to all the questions in the quiz.

Then you could use a series of `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements to record your users' answers in the database.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO pro_NoMusic (userid, question, answer, ts)
      VALUES ($_POST[user_id], '8a','$_POST[question8a]', NOW())
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE answer='$_POST[question8a]', ts=NOW())";
```